# value YpartialUnification is not a member of scala.tools.nsc.Settings

Tags: scala, scala-cats, ammonite

I'm trying to run scala cats in REPL. Following cat's [instructions](https://typelevel.org/cats/faq.html#ammonite) I have installed ammonite REPL and put following imports in `predef.sc`

```
nterp.configureCompiler(_.settings.YpartialUnification.value = true)
import $ivy.`org.typelevel::cats-core:2.2.0-M1`, cats.implicits._
```

I got this error when run `amm`.

```
predef.sc:1: value YpartialUnification is not a member of scala.tools.nsc.Settings
val res_0 = interp.configureCompiler(_.settings.YpartialUnification.value = true)
                                                ^
Compilation Failed
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Scala 2.13 partial unification is [enabled by default](https://github.com/scala/scala/releases/tag/v2.13.0) and `-Ypartial-unification` flag has been removed by [Partial unification unconditional; deprecate -Xexperimental #6309](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/6309)

> Partial unification is now enabled unless -Xsource:2.12 is specified.
>   The -Ypartial-unification flag has been removed and the -Xexperimental
>   option, which is now redundant, has been deprecated.

thus the compiler [no longer](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/pull/2949) accepts `-Ypartial-unification`.