# Sequence and Traverse in Cats Scala to map a types

Tags: scala, types, sequence, scala-cats, applicative

I have this a value of type `List[EitherT[IO, String, Int]]` and I want to do sequence on it in order to map it into `EitherT[IO,String, List[Int]]`

I read and I found sequence method
but It gives me an error saying that it needs an implicit Applicative of [G] how can this be resolved

Comment: ialmostwouldhave[downvotedbecau.se/nomcve/](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to guess the reasons of your compile error ("needs an implicit `Applicative[G]`") without [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please provide the one.

- Before Cats 2.2.0 it was necessary to import instances

  https://meta.plasm.us/posts/2019/09/30/implicit-scope-and-cats/

  https://github.com/typelevel/cats/releases/tag/v2.2.0

  http://eed3si9n.com/herding-cats/import-guide.html

  [Why is import cats.implicits._ no longer necessary for importing type class instances?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63865759/why-is-import-cats-implicits-no-longer-necessary-for-importing-type-class-inst)

  ```
  import cats.instances.either._ // or cats.instances.all._
  import cats.instances.list._ // or cats.instances.all._
  import cats.syntax.traverse._ // or cats.syntax.all._
  // or cats.implicits._
  ```

  Starting from Cats 2.2.0 you still need to import syntaxes but no longer need to import instances.
- Before Scala 2.13.0 you had to add to `build.sbt`

  ```
  scalacOptions += "-Ypartial-unification"
  ```

  https://github.com/typelevel/cats/issues/2948

  http://eed3si9n.com/herding-cats/partial-unification.html

  [value YpartialUnification is not a member of scala.tools.nsc.Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61035986/value-ypartialunification-is-not-a-member-of-scala-tools-nsc-settings)

  https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/7ak9c5/ypartialunification/
- Or maybe you need to specify generics (which were not inferred)

  ```
  val l: List[Either[String, Int]] = ???
  val l1: List[EitherT[IO, String, Int]] = ???
  l.sequence[({ type G[X] = Either[String, X] })#G, Int] // using type lambda
  l1.sequence[({ type G[X] = EitherT[IO, String, X] })#G, Int] // using type lambda
  l.sequence[Either[String, *], Int] // using kind-projector
  l1.sequence[EitherT[IO, String, *], Int] // using kind-projector
  ```
- Or you can unwrap-wrap `EitherT`

  ```
  EitherT(
    l1.traverse(_.value)
      .map(
        _.sequence[Either[String, *], Int]
      )
  )
  ```
- If you write a generic method maybe it's enough to add a context bound

  ```
  def foo[G[_]: Applicative] = {
  //            ^^^^^^^^^^^   here

    // ... using .sequence ...
  }
  ```